# Pre-fill the checkbox with url

Tags: php, html, url, checkbox

I understand that we can pre-fill some data in a HTML form using the URL.
For example, [www.example.com/?itemname=sth](http://www.example.com/?itemname=sth)

May I know would there be a similar way for me to pre-check a checkbox through the URL?

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">
       <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input product_check" id="Tutor_subject_1" name="Maths" value="Maths" 
<?php if (isset($_GET['itemname']) && $_GET['itemname'] === 'sth' ): ?> 
           document.getElementByName("Maths").click();
       <?php endif; ?>>Maths<br>
          </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you @jrswgtr. I have one more follow up question. The above setting is actually the filter of my result page. Your solution is workable but it simply checked the box but doesn't pass the value of the selected items to my SQL like it usually does. May I know how could i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, do an if check on the `$_GET` parameter:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       class="form-check-input product_check"
       id="Tutor_subject_1"
       value="Maths"
       <?php if (isset($_GET['itemname']) && $_GET['itemname'] === 'sth' ): ?> 
           checked
       <?php endif; ?> />
```

Comment: Thank you @jrswgtr. I have one more follow up question. The above setting is actually the filter of my result page. Your solution is workable but it simply checked the box but doesn't pass the value of the selected items to my SQL like it usually does. May I know how could i change it?

Comment: @sevenine I'm not sure about the SQL part you are talking about. Please include the part of the code where you do your SQL stuff to your question

Comment: Hi @jrswgtr, I realize that my code is triggered by a click to the checkbox.                                   i have changed "checked" to "document.getElementByName("Maths").click()" and add a name="Maths", but turns out it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the changed code to your question, With only this comment it's too vague to help you.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I have made changes accordingly. What I want is with that URL, if everything matches then click on the checkbox. Thanks for your time @jrswgtr

Comment: insert a `<script>` tag around the Javascript. Also use the ID instead of name to target your element `document.getElementById("Tutor_subject_1");`

Comment: I have tried that but turns out it didnt click the checkbox :( @jrswgtr

Comment: I would advice against using the `click()` function on the element. Instead execute the same JS code that's triggered by the click on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php for this solution .

```
<?php
$item =  (isset($_GET['itemname']) && $_GET['itemname'] === 'sth') ? $_GET['itemname'] : '';
?>

<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item">
       <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input product_check" id="Tutor_subject_1" value="Maths" <?php if($item) {echo "checked";} ?> >Maths<br>
          </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @ahmed. I have one more follow up question. The above setting is actually the filter of my result page. Your solution is workable but it simply checked the box but doesn't pass the value of the selected items to my SQL like it usually does. May I know how could i change it?